# How do I create a function to loop Man-Kendell test through pixels of timeseries DEMs

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame that contains elevation values from annual time series DEMs (2010-2021).
I previously created a function to calculate the slope, p-value, R2, and RMSE of each pixels elevation in the DEM using lm (based on X and Y location) and export them to a separate dataframe. Ultimately I want to know the magnitude, direction, and significance of the change in elevation for each pixel.

```
#summary of the dataframe (all.z.fltr) that contains my data
summary(all.z.fltr)
       X                Y                Year            elev          year.num     
 Min.   :586013   Min.   :7914066   2010   :14413   Min.   :1.104   Min.   : 1.000  
 1st Qu.:586028   1st Qu.:7914078   2011   :14413   1st Qu.:1.382   1st Qu.: 3.000  
 Median :586038   Median :7914084   2014   :14413   Median :1.431   Median : 6.000  
 Mean   :586038   Mean   :7914084   2019   :14413   Mean   :1.458   Mean   : 6.091  
 3rd Qu.:586049   3rd Qu.:7914089   2013   :14412   3rd Qu.:1.526   3rd Qu.: 9.000  
 Max.   :586063   Max.   :7914102   2017   :14412   Max.   :1.808   Max.   :12.000  
                                    (Other):72043    
#Dataframe 
head(all.z.fltr)
          X       Y Year     elev year.num
1: 586013.1 7914084 2010 1.630842        1
2: 586013.1 7914084 2011 1.582396        2
3: 586013.1 7914084 2012 1.490715        3
4: 586013.1 7914084 2013 1.441739        4
5: 586013.1 7914084 2014 1.418420        5
6: 586013.1 7914084 2015 1.352640        6
```

```r
#code to extract slope from each pixel using lm
extract.slope.fx <- function(df) {
  fit <- lm(elev ~ year.num, data = df)
  return(list(intercept=coef(fit)[1], 
              slope=coef(fit)[2],
              rsqaure=summary(fit)$r.squared,
              rmse=sqrt(mean(fit$residuals^2)),
              p=(summary(fit)$coefficients[,4]),
              raster.count=length(fit$fitted.values))) }

#Create dataframe with output values
slopes.all <- all.z.fltr[extract.slope.fx(.SD), by="X,Y"]
```

I want to do the same thing but this time using Man-Kendal test. I need a function that will test the significance of the slope for each pixel across the time series dataset and export a data frame with the slope, p-value, RMSE and or any other metric of variability.

It seems the function to do the same thing for a Man-Kendal test is nothing like the function i wrote to loop a lm through each pixel. I do not even know where to begin for the Man-Kendal test.